# What statistical test would be the best to use?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I am currently working on a project for my internship. In the beginning, I was told I was going to have different variables to use, so now I am having to change what my statistical test will be for my analysis. I have 1 independent and 1 dependent variable. The dependent variable is BMI status (underweight, normal, overweight, and obese) and the independent is grade level (first, third, and sixth grade). I am assuming that these variables are both ordinal. Would that be correct? If so, what statistical test would be best to use? I was going to use a simple linear regression with different variables but now that they have changed to categorical variables I am no longer able to conduct that kind of regression. I am having trouble figuring out what would be appropriate with two ordinal ones.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use generalized linear modeling (GLM) to handle outcome variables that are not normally distributed. For your case, with ordinal BMI categories variable, you can use a special case of GLM called ordinal logistic regression. [This website](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/dae/) has examples on how to do this in STATA, SAS, SPSS, Mplus, and R. To handle the grade-level predictor variable, I would recommend just treating these as separate categories (e.g., use [dummy coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics))). There are approaches for modeling the ordered nature of categorical variables, but this seems overkill for an internship project and only three categories.